# Angular Tesseract.js output result is not correct

Tags: angular, tesseract

I try to use latest version of tesseract.js for angular libraly.
And i got a problem that my output result is not really correct.

Here is my result.

```
I TE [CET EST IN 3
VEN PRESS (mabe) TMP (mig) UF VOLUME (UF GOAL © UF RATE am N
200 7 1.33 9)
° bz
Ip Gs)
280-4 84-g¢ 2.30- 30) =
] Ty (STOP
] 1 DIALY TEWP  |§ dl
: ] ! |
= | - | - T CONOUCT
jad © ton © 0.000 Tie |
j OIALY FLOW
|
(sL/nin) &)
— = 8. FLW (at/ain)
1) 6 8 Fo JE I I EE (= 1D
```

And here is my image.

[image]

A number in a black color was not detect.

What should i do ?? Thank you.

I try to reduce a image noise and resize my image already.